# How to set tablecolumn's value when it has a different object than the tableview

Tags: java, hibernate, javafx, tableview, tablecolumn

when im setting value on the tablecolumn it always errors out saying "Cannot read from unreadable property name" name is the field i am accessing which is on product class

pseudocode:

```
`
public class OrderItem() {
Integer Id;
String comment
Product product;

*getter and setter method*
}

public class Product() {

String name


*getter and setter method*
}


public class Controller(){
    @FXML
    private TableView<OrderItem> tblItems;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Product, String> colProduct;

public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

colProduct.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Product, String>("name"));
//rest of code where i pull data
}
}
`
```

Comment: Don't post pseudocode - will get you pseudo answers. Please post real code!

Comment: The first type parameter in the `TableColumn` *must* match the type parameter in the `TableView`. In this scenario, you need to implement the `cellValueFactory` directly to map from the `OrderItem` representing the row to the value to be displayed in the cell. A `PropertyValueFactory` cannot be used in this scenario (it can only be used when the value to be displayed is a direct property of the row value).

Comment: @James_D theres no cellValueFactory method but there is cellValueFactoryProperty. would you be able to give me a sample on how to implement your solution

Comment: There's a `setCellValueFactory(...)` method; you pass the implementation of the factory to that method.

Comment: guys my question is already answered. pls see link provided by james_d as this is a duplicate question